# & as a Arithmetic Operator in PHP

Tags: php, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

I am working on some legacy code where I came across the following function:

```
function is_odd($number) {
   return $number & 1; // 0 = even, 1 = odd
}
```

I have never seen a method to check if a number is odd written like that before and am just trying to understand what they actually are doing.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: This is more of a mathematical question rather than a PHP question to be honest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&` is a [bitwise-and](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND), it basically works so that for every bit that is `1` in both operands, it yields `1` in the resulting value and `0` for all other bits. If you convert any number to its bit representation, you quickly see that it's the lowest bit that determines whether a number is even or odd, for example:

```
   5 = 101
  10 = 1010
  13 = 1101
1030 = 10000000110
```

The lowest bit (the one on the very right, also called the least significant bit) is 1 for every odd number and 0 for every even number. Doing `$n & 1` will always yield `0` for every other bit than the lowest bit (because the number 1 only has one bit, you can imagine that the rest of the bits are left-padded with 0 to match the length of the other operand). So basically the operation boils down to comparing the lowest bit of the operands, and `1 & 1` is 1, all other combinations are 0. So basically when the `$n & 1` yields 1, it means the number is odd, otherwise it's even.

**EDIT.**

Here's a few examples to demonstrate how the bitwise-and works for the example values I gave earlier, the number in the parenthesis is the original decimal number:

```
  101 (5)
& 001 (1)
  ---
  001 (1) = true


  1010 (10)
& 0001 (1)
  ----
  0000 (0) = false


  1101 (13)
& 0001 (1)
  ----
  0001 (1) = true


  10000000110 (1030)
& 00000000001 (1)
  -----------
  00000000000 (0) = false
```

From this you can easily see that the result is only true when both operands' right-most bits are 1.